How do I force GRASS to create cells with equal X and Y resolutions?
I'm trying to average several rasters with X and Y resolutions of 0.0083333333 into a single map using r.series.accumulate from within QGIS. Strangely the output has X and Y resolutions that are different: 0.00833333330001617 and 0.00833333330003756 respectively. Not massively different I know but my subsequent processing requires the text representations of the resolutions to be identical otherwise it fails.
Here's the script produced by qgis_process:
g.proj -c wkt="<local dir>/processing_LKGFKx/ddbe8d5f23c0426c8c523b7d662e8b72/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="r1.bil" band=1 output="rast_674d9fdd8d4222" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="r2.bil" band=1 output="rast_674d9fdd8d4223" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="r3.bil" band=1 output="rast_674d9fdd8d4224" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="r4.bil" band=1 output="rast_674d9fdd8d4225" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="r5.bil" band=1 output="rast_674d9fdd8d4226" --overwrite -o
g.region n=-3.1751392361499997 s=-35.22513910795001 e=-52.708472731349985 w=-81.33347261684999 res=0.0083333333
r.series.accumulate
input=rast_674d9fdd8d4222,rast_674d9fdd8d4223,rast_674d9fdd8d4224,rast_674d9fdd8d4225,rast_674d9fdd8d4226 method="mean" limits=0.0,200000.0 -f output=output079c53e7d7c942ceb1b58249ca8f497c --overwrite
g.region raster=output079c53e7d7c942ceb1b58249ca8f497c
r.out.gdal input="output079c53e7d7c942ceb1b58249ca8f497c" output="mean.bil" format="EHdr" createopt="COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite

Truncate both to micrometers and they're equal..

You should really make your process to tolerate small differences which tend to be unavoidable when dealing with floating point numbers.

Understood. Unfortunately I have no access to the code for the subsequent processing which is external to QGIS. Looks like I'll have to edit the header files manually.
It is unfortunate that GDAL does not clip resolutions to a sensible number of decimal places, 6 would be ample.
